# Unit Test not running in vs 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Unit tests discovered but not running at all in VS 2017 for c#. I can see the green bar on the test explorer but eventually nothing happens it does not provide any result fail or pass.

I have tried clearing up the ComponentModelCache directory but it did not helped in any way.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Nunit Test Adapter?

Comment: How are  you trying to run the unit test? Discovering the tests does not run them... you need to select tests, right click on tests and select `Run Tests...`..

Comment: Have you tried Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture --> x64 before running the tests?

Comment: the problem was resolved after updating the test adapters in Nuget package manager

Comment: You should post how you resolved it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It got it fixed by installing NUnit3TestAdapter nuget package. Only having NUnit nuget is not enough.

Comment: The screen shot indicates MSTest, so your answer does not really apply in its current form.

Comment: Right, you can infer is MSTest because of the attribute decorator [TestMethod]. Since this also applies to NUnit, the partial true answer is installing the Test Adapter for the Unit Test framework being used. Partial true answer because I don't know if this also applies to xUnit or another unit testing framework.